# Attempt to index local 'tooltip' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

Please help.  I'm trying to fix this code and I'm just not seeing the error. I am very inexperienced and appreciate any help you can give me.  Thanks.

Error: UberInventory-6.8.lua:1325: attempt to index local 'tooltip' (a nil value)

Code - beginning at line 1320

```
function UberInventory_HookTooltip( tooltip )
    -- From global to local
    local UBI_Hooks = UBI_Hooks;

    -- Store default script
    local tooltipName = tooltip:GetName();
    UBI_Hooks["OnTooltipSetItem"][tooltipName] = tooltip:GetScript( "OnTooltipSetItem" );
    UBI_Hooks["OnTooltipCleared"][tooltipName] = tooltip:GetScript( "OnTooltipCleared" );

    -- Set new script to handle OntooltipSetItem
    tooltip:SetScript( "OnTooltipSetItem", function( self, ... )
        -- From global to local
        local UBI_Hooks = UBI_Hooks;

        -- Get tooltip name
        local tooltipName = self:GetName();

        -- Call default script
        if ( UBI_Hooks["OnTooltipSetItem"][tooltipName] ) then
            UBI_Hooks["OnTooltipSetItem"][tooltipName]( self, ... );
        end;

        -- Call new script (adds the item information)
        UberInventory_AddItemInfo( self );

        -- Turn on UberInventory indicator
        self.UBI_InfoAdded = true;
    end );

    -- Set new script to handle OnTooltipCleared
    tooltip:SetScript( "OnTooltipCleared", function( self, ... )
        -- From global to local
        local UBI_Hooks = UBI_Hooks;

        -- Get tooltip name
        local tooltipName = self:GetName();

        -- Force reset of fonts (maxlines is a custom attribute added within the UberInventory_AddItemInfo function)
        if ( self.maxlines ) then
            local txtLeft, txtRight;
            for i = 1, self.maxlines do
                txtLeft = _G[self:GetName().."TextLeft"..i];
                txtRight = _G[self:GetName().."TextRight"..i];
                if ( txtLeft ) then txtLeft:SetFontObject( GameTooltipText ); end;
                if ( txtRight ) then txtRight:SetFontObject( GameTooltipText ); end;
            end;
        end;

        -- Call default script
        if ( UBI_Hooks["OnTooltipCleared"][tooltipName] ) then
            UBI_Hooks["OnTooltipCleared"][tooltipName]( self, ... );
        end;

        -- Turn off UberInventory indicator
        self.UBI_InfoAdded = false;
    end );
 end;
```

And here is the code from line 2074 to 2087 where "HookTooltip" is called

```
function UberInventory_Install_Hooks()
    -- Hook the Tooltips (OnTooltipSetItem, OnTooltipCleared)
    UberInventory_HookTooltip( GameTooltip );
    UberInventory_HookTooltip( ItemRefTooltip );
    UberInventory_HookTooltip( ShoppingTooltip1 );
    UberInventory_HookTooltip( ShoppingTooltip2 );
    UberInventory_HookTooltip( ShoppingTooltip3 );

    -- Hook mail stuff
    UBI_Hooks["ReturnInboxItem"] = ReturnInboxItem;
    ReturnInboxItem = UberInventory_ReturnInboxItem;
    UBI_Hooks["SendMail"] = SendMail;
    SendMail = UberInventory_SendMail;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you are calling (`UberInventory_HookTooltip`) gets a `nil` value as `toolkit` parameter. When you then try to call a method of that `tookit` object (`tooltip:GetName()`), you get an expected error as indicated: "attempt to index local 'tooltip' (a nil value)". The code tries to find a field `GetName` in the table that should be stored in `tooltip` and fails to do that (to "index" the table) as there value is nil. You need to check the code that calls the function to make sure it passes the correct value. It's not possible to give you any further help without seeing the code that calls `UberInventory_HookTooltip`.

Comment: function UberInventory_Install_Hooks()
    -- Hook the Tooltips (OnTooltipSetItem, OnTooltipCleared)
    UberInventory_HookTooltip( GameTooltip );
    UberInventory_HookTooltip( ItemRefTooltip );
    UberInventory_HookTooltip( ShoppingTooltip1 );
    UberInventory_HookTooltip( ShoppingTooltip2 );
    UberInventory_HookTooltip( ShoppingTooltip3 );

    -- Hook mail stuff
    UBI_Hooks["ReturnInboxItem"] = ReturnInboxItem;
    ReturnInboxItem = UberInventory_ReturnInboxItem;
    UBI_Hooks["SendMail"] = SendMail;
    SendMail = UberInventory_SendMail;
end;

Comment: One of those calls passes `nil` as its value. If you want to figure out which one, add something like this as the first line to the function call: `if tooltip == nil then error('passed nil '..debug.traceback()) end`.